# Can Natural Weapons be considered part of the Close Weapon group?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, weapons, fighter, natural-weapon

Since unarmed strikes are listed under both the Fighter "Natural" weapon group and "Close" weapon group, could claw attacks possibly fall under both for the sake of applying bonuses given by the Brawler Archetype of Fighter?

Answer (score 1):

By strict RAW, no, they do not qualify as Close Weapons. Natural Weapons is a single grouping of all of the Natural Weapons. It was clearly a design decision to not include any Natural attacks in the Close Weapons group.